# Comparing char in a string to another char in C

Tags: c, string, char, compare

what I have is a string that I get from txt file.

```
fgets(num_string, lenght, file);
num_string = "011110110101"
```

So than I select the first number and display it:

```
printf("Number: %c", num_string[0]);
```

After that my program gets all the numbers in string with this loop and it should then check each number if its 0 or 1:

```
for(j=0; j<=11; j++){
                printf("numbers: %c\n", num_string[j]);

                if(strcmp(num_string[j], zero)==0){
                    num_of_zeros++;
                    printf("\nNum of zeros: %d", num_of_zeros);
                }
                else{
                    num_of_ones++;
                    printf("\nNum of ones: %d", num_of_ones);
                }
}
```

But the **if** statement does not want to work. Here is the problem that it writes in terminal:

```
AOC_2021_day_3.c: In function 'main':
AOC_2021_day_3.c:27:27: warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
                 if(strcmp(num_string[j], zero)==0){
                           ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from AOC_2021_day_3.c:3:0:
c:\mingw\include\string.h:77:38: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'
 _CRTIMP __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  int strcmp (const char *, const char *) __MINGW_ATTRIB_PURE;
                                      ^~~~~~
```

**I would appreciate any help :D**

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag. This question is clearly about C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strcmp` is for comparing to cstrings. In this case, you do not need `strcmp` at all. You want to check whether a specific character inside `num_string` is `0` or not. The `if(strcmp(num_string[j], zero)==0)` statement can be replaced with `if(num_string[j] == '0')`.

Comment: So I have tried it this way but then I get a problem message like this:

**AOC_2021_day_3.c: In function 'main':
AOC_2021_day_3.c:27:33: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
                 if(num_string[j]=="0"){**

Comment: It's `'0'` and not `"0"`. They are not same.

Comment: Oh thats the catch... I have to look more into that. Now its working. Thank you very much.